# Sessions in PHP and login confusion

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication

I am a little confused with the use of sessions in PHP, esp. with maintaining user sessions after login. So to maintain sessions, one of the methods that we can use is using the session_start() in PHP.

Now session_start() generates a unique sessionID and sends a cookie to the browser with this id, if I am correct (as I read from several resources).

Now lets take a simple user login use case where I need to maintain sessions. So typically and a very simple scenario, user logs enters his username and password in the respective fields on the form. Then user presses the submit button.

The POST values get sent to the PHP script, say login.php, that handles sessions. Inside login.php I check for $_POST['username'] and $_POST['password'] to see if it matches the values present in the db. Let's assume that the values match.

So a new session should be created now, right? Why do we include session_start() in the beginning of login.php then?

Secondly, so after the session is started and a sessionID is created it is sent in a cookie to the browser and is also recorded in the $_SESSIONS global variable. So now the thing is where in all this did we bind this session with this particular user ? I understand that since the cookie will be sent by the user with every request, and since the server has the same sessionID, as in the cookie, maintained at its end as well, the server would know that the request is coming from the same user. But then we are not recording this sessionID explicitly anywhere (in the db etc.) for this user. So if i need all the other details about this user, how would i get it ? So how exactly is the sessionID connected with a particular user's details stored in the db ?

So to give an example, let's assume that in the above case the user we discussed was say USER A. For a second user, say USER B also all the above would hold true. So now the server will definitely be able to distinguish between requests from both these users because of the 2 different sessionIDs that will be sent by these users in the cookies with their requests. But on the server side, how will USER A's request be linked with USER A's details in the db and how will USER B's request be linked with USER B's details in the db ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to clear your confusion I will go point by point

`So a new session should be created now, right? Why do we include session_start() in the beginning of login.php then?`

We include [session_start()](https://www.php.net/function.session-start) because it says PHP to start session then and then you can store any information in `$_SESSION`, so `session_start()` is necessary

---

`But on the server side, how will USER A's request be linked with USER A's details in the db and how will USER B's request be linked with USER B's details in the db ?`

When user login's we store user's (unique) information in $_SESSION.

For example if USER A is logged in than I will get his ID from db and store it in `$_SESSION['uid']` and other info if needed.

Then when I want other information of USER A on any page I will just get his ID from $_SESSION and make query according to this.

---

I hope this will clear your confusion.

Comment: Hi @TechnoKnol thanks for the reply. I get my second answer sound and clear. However for my 1st question, what I meant was So a new session should be created NOW, right? Why do we include session_start() in the BEGINNING of login.php then?

Comment: have you referred `session_start()` on php.net ? 
`session_start()` only tells PHP to start session not to store any info. So if you `session_start()` anywhere and not store any info in `$_SESSION` then it won't allow user to login.

Comment: I read it here http://www.sitepoint.com/users-php-sessions-mysql/ that session_start() will auto set a cookie.

Comment: also another point is when the user sends the cookie containing the sessionID, does it get auto checked with the one saved on the server side or do we need to explicitly script it and check it?

Comment: server auto checks it. We don't need and pesky script.

Answer (score 1):

After checking that You had a POST to your page, you can set the $_SESSION variable to hold some information of the user already logged in for further use.

At first you'll have to start your session using `session_start()` as you've mentioned.
After that check if the user's provided credentials matches the info in your DB.
Now if the user should be logged in try this ( or sth like it ...)

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
$_SESSION['username']= $_POST['username'];
```

and store every other info You might need later.
Accessing these info is as easy as storing them. simply use `$_SESSION['variable-name']` to access the stored value in your session
for example to get 'username' of a currently logged in user, you can use `$username = $_SESSION['username'];`
I hope it helped.

Comment: I understand this. Thanks @Mithredate Now a second thing would be, so from the security perspective, if USER B is just able to get access to  USER A's cookies, and send them with his request, will he be able to get access to USER A's data ?

Comment: yes, of course USER B will be able to logged in as USER A. But there are lots of ways to deny this.

Comment: Cookies for sessions are supposed to be stored server-side, so if by any chance a user would be able to access your stored cookies, he might be able to get whatever he wants way too easier ...

Answer (score 0):

So basically i got a clearer understanding about sessions from http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0dq5Sj9jyKU.

Just a gentle note: -This answer is to help myself understand sessions better.

SO basically the PHPSessionID and the session created on the server corresponding a particular user has the following relationship and workflow: -

1. user is not logged in so far.
2. user enters credentials on the front end form and hits submit.
3. the login.php (server side) script that handles log ins is passed the form data.
4. user's credentials are matched against the ones stored in the database.
5. if they match, then a session for this user should be started.
6. so to do this, in login.php in the beginning itself, before any other code we need to write session_start(). Now what session_start() does in this case here is this: -

   > - it generates a PHPSessionId
   > - stores it in a cookie on the client
7. Now since the user was authenticated, he is given the Welcome screen or any screen that the user needs to be sent to after a successful login.
8. let's say the user is sent to welcome_member.php.
9. so basically when I am saying that the user is SENT to welcome_member.php, what i mean is that typically the client is made to request the page welcome_member.php (say for example by using the header() in php after login or say by making the user click on a certain link after login to visit this page, as shown in the example shown in the youtube link above).
10. when a request is sent from the client, it carries with it all the cookies pertaining to the site. So one of these cookies here contains our PHPSessionID, which is also sent along with this request to the page welcome_member.php.
11. now welcome_member.php needs to display information specific to the logged in user.
12. so to do this, we do a small modification in steps 5 and 6 above. So after the user's credentials are matched successfully, we also create a session variable wherein we store some unique information, specific to this user, into this variable. Say for example we store the user's Unique ID into the session variable loggedInUser as: -

    > $_SESSION['loggedInUser']= $userID; //where userId is a the unique userID of the user retrieved from the database.
13. now there could be many users using the application. So for all these users all of the above would be true. So the above mentioned sessions and session variables would be created for all the users who login successfully.
14. so there should be a way for the server to distinguish between all these sessions.

    > so this is where the PHPSessionId gets into the picture. On the server, PHP distinguishes between the different sessions using this PHPSessionId, as for each user this ID would be unique. So depending on this id, PHP chooses which particular session to pick up from its internal storage. So say for example, for User A, the PHPSessionId generated was 1234 for example. So this would be stored internally by PHP with for example a label saying "This session holds the information for User A". Similarly for User B, say the PHPSessionId generated was 6789 for example. So this would be stored internally by PHP with for example a label saying "This session holds the information for User B".
15. now coming back to point 12 above, where welcome_member.php needed to access some information specific to our logged in user.
16. so here, in welcome_member.php, to access the current user's session and all the information that we had earlier stored in this session (just the userID in our case), we need to use session_start() again on this page (and of course again in the beginning of the page welcome_member.php before any other code).
17. now in this case, session_start() does not restart another session as was the case in step 6 above. But instead, in this case, since the page, welcome_member.php, was called from the client, it already has a valid PHPSessionID in the cookie. And so as explained in Step 14 and the following paragraph above, this session id is used to retrieve all the information (just the userID in our case) stored in the session of this logged in user.
18. coming back to welcome_member.php again, now that we have the uniqueId of our user stored in the session variable $_SESSION['loggedInUser'], we can use this value to fetch any other details about the user from the database.
19. now for every page that needs to access information of this session (or in other words, in which ever page user session needs to be maintained), we simply call session_start() and things follow as explained in step 17 above.